# Print both matched and unmatched lines; awk: print matched group

Tags: sed, awk

1) How to use sed to append a mark to the lines matching a pattern and at the same time print also the lines that does not match the pattern?

If I do this '`sed -n s/pattern/pattern mark/p`', the all the unmatched lines will not be printed.

[solved]

Comment: Just found out that "gensub" can solve my 2nd question. So i still have the 1st question to solve. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not suppress the default output using `-n`, sed will print out all lines:

```
sed 's/pattern/pattern mark/'
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sed question, just do something like:

```
sed '/pattern/s/$/pattern marker/'
```

to append pattern marker to lines which match

Answer (score 0):

NOT exactly answers the question, but one way if you want to add some text in the following line is to use the append command of the `GNU` version of `sed`:

```
sed -e '/pattern/ a mark' infile
```

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Ok. Now realised. Missunderstood the question. Thank you for pointing out the error.